# Is there a wait-list functionality planned or already implemented?

Tags: 8, rng

I just took a first look on the [RNG Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rng). In the Readme, it is called the successor of the Drupal [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) Module.

Is there a wait-list functionality planned or already implemented?
Maybe I'm not getting it right and its already implemented via Rules?

Any help would be welcome...

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for wait lists at this time, however the API has a tagging system not exposed via UI, which is designed to support a list systems.

I encourage you to take a look at [RNG Ecosystem](https://github.com/dpi/rng/issues/76), and give some feedback on your requirements for wait lists.